# how many images are there in particular category based on category order getting a row in laravel eloquent relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Currently my categories are displayed in descending order.

```
public function categories(){
    $categories = Category::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    return view('categories', ['categories' => $categories]);
}
```

My images table has a `category_id` column which contain the id of the category they belong to.

My Image model has a `belongsTo()` relationship with Category model:

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

And my Category model has a `hasMany()` relationship with Image model:

```
public function images(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
}
```

I've been wondering whether I could order the categories based on how many images belong to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

by using **withCount** elequent method in laravel

```
Category::withCount('images')->orderBy('images_count', 'desc')->get();
```

for more information read laravel official article [counting-related-models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)